# Am I calculating the Gini coefficient correctly?

Tags: microeconomics, statistics, public-economics

I calculated the Gini coefficient through a statistical program (MATLAB), and it came out much larger than I expected. I think I got the Gini coefficient formula right, but I don't know where I went wrong. Here's my calculation process. (I used file 1 with income, household size, and quarters table (1990/1Q-2022/4Q) and file 2 with CPI (2020=100)).

**Step1**
Calculating real income: dividing each the income by the CPI for corresponding quarter and multiply by 100.

**Step2**
Equalizing income: dividing the value obtained above by the square root of the number of household members.

**Step3**
Adding the number of people in the household for all households with the same income.

**Step4**
Calculating the Gini coefficient according to the following formula

**Formula**

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(Y_i) \sum_{j=1}^n f(Y_j)\vert Y_i-Y_j\vert}{2\bar Y}
$$

where $Y_i$is the income of ith household, $f(Y_i)$ is the frequency of the people of income, and $\bar{Y}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f\left(Y_i\right)Y_i}$

I'm having a hard time keeping up with the reviews. Thank you for your help. I will share the MATLAB code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you describe make sense except for the last one where you presumably forgot $t$ subscript. If you did not forgot it but it was deliberate choice it is very strange one since it does not make sense to look at inequality in pooled cross-section in an economy that presumably experienced growth.

Comment: You're right, I forgot. I distinguished income by period t and found the Gini coefficient for each t separately. The part I'm most unsure about is step1. Is it correct to run step1, which finds the real income at all t first, or after step2, which equalizes the income?